# c# Redirect tcp/Http Requests

Tags: c#, python-requests

Is there is anyway to forward a http/tcp requests to another client on the same network on the same subnet ? example send http content to another client on the subnet ?

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: zerkms how can i forward/send requests to another clients on the network ?

Comment: Using a forwarder.

Comment: how to develop it in .NET

Comment: You take a keyboard and write some code.

Comment: it calls what a proxy ?